# how to display wp_editor in a page

Tags: wp-editor

I am making my theme. 
I am using wp_editor in front-end to submit post.

I submit through wp_editor in the specific page, and this being displayed in single.php. 
At single.php I am using

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

The problem is when I put enter-key (like br tag) in a post that is several blank row, these blank rows are disappeared. All contents are shown without blank row. so it looks not cool.

My first language is not English, so I am not sure that my expression is good to explain my intention.

I mean, I want like this (A). but the content shows like (B). There's no blank rows..

(A)
My name is mike. Hi. 
Hahaha. you look nice.

And what is you name?

(B)
My name is mike. Hi. 
Hahaha. you look nice.
And what is you name?

Can someone have any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, there is a lack of `wp_autop()` and other formatting functions that get applied to the `the_content` filter. The editor does not save `<p>` tags at all, but later on line-breaks are converted into paragraphs by `wp_autop()`.

I would like to say about meta content, for that like to recreate the default filters. I do this because some plugins add things by the `the_content` filter.

There is some filters like below:-

```
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'wptexturize' );
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'convert_smilies' );
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'convert_chars' );
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'shortcode_unautop' );
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'prepend_attachment');
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'do_shortcode' );
```

Place the below code where you want to display your actual data.

```
$your_description = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_name', true);
echo apply_filters( 'meta_content', $your_description );
```

Answer (score 1):

I remember banging my head against the wall trying to solve this one :) Check if you have properly initialized your post with `the_post()` in the loop.

If it doesn't help, you can apply content filter manually like this:

```
global $post;
echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
```

FYI `the_content` filter contains hooks that expand shortcodes, wrap all things in paragraphs and do other formatting